# copy fields from one record into another record in the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with a number of course details with the following structure

```
CourseName
BasicInfo
CourseDetails
OtherInfo
AgeGroup
StartDate
```

There are a number of courses which have the same CourseName and BasicInfo, CourseDetails but seperate Age and StartDate.  The course name for every record already exists but the BasicInfo and CourseDetails is empty.

I have created a form for the user to enter the details.  So they get to the first course and enter the details.  What I need then is for them to be able to then copy those two fields into each of the records where the CourseName matches.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to do that.  Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you repeat the same basicInfo and courseDetails multiple times, you should consider putting that information in a seperate table. That way you could include that information every time the course gets selected, and changes only need to be made in 1 place. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I think the following structure should send you in the right direction:

```
Table: Course
id (PK)
courseName
basicInfo
courseDetails

Table: CourseDate
Id (PK)
startDate
courseId (FK)
```

I hope this helps you at least a little bit. Not sure if I interpreted your question a 100% correct though.

Edited after OP commented.

Comment: Yeah i thought of that, but its only an initial copy.  They may want to change the information for each course later on.

Comment: Do you mean the basicInfo? Because another form where you can update the Course-table would solve that. I'm talking about forms because I presume you are working in MSAccess?

If you do not keep the fields you want to 'copy' seperated, you will need to change them everywhere you have 'copied' them once a value of one of those fields changes.

Comment: Basically, We have 895 records, almost half of these are the same course but on different days.  As an initial excersise the user needs to enter the basic info and course details for the 450 different courses, which will then complete the records for all the courses.  They might then want to go into the form and change each individual records course details.  Yeah I'm using Access, this is what is confusing me - I've not touched it in 10 years.

Comment: And I would not touch it in the next ten years as well, if I were you ! But that's another matter. Now, I understand your problem a bit better, and with the information you gave me I would do the following. First, make a table 'Course' , with your '450' courses and all of their required information. On the other hand I'd make a table 'CourseDate' where you have a foreign key referring to the course and a date. That way you can add as many dates for the courses as you want. You then could query the courses like this: `SELECT c.*, cd.date FROM Course c, CourseDate cd WHERE cd.courseId = c.id`